# Quarkus remote application testing in dev mode

Tags: junit5, quarkus

When we run `@QuarkusTest` annotated tests, one of these tests run the Quarkus test extension and start `Quarkus` in dev mode. Quarkus will then remain running for the duration of the test run. This is how we can achieve fast debugging.

But my use case is bit different from it. I need to verify an application which is running remotely. Is there a way I can tell Quakus not to start application while I'm using the `@QuarkusTest` annotation?

one possible way to achieve it that I simply write JUnits and boiler-plate code to connect the api and then verify it. However, I want to use Quakus framework while stopping Quarkus not to run application.